react native document scanner issues with scanning
How can I implement a document scanning feature with react-native-camera?
I have worked with react-native-document-scanner
and it works very well but has a few limitations both on Android and iOS for me.
It scans the document very well if you have a dark background as that of the document.
Now there are two cases that I want to handle:

If I keep the document in the air maybe holding it with my hand, then If I scan that document at that time it fails to scan it properly. Here are the two images one where it works with a dark background and another fail case.

image1
image2
image1 is the problem and I want it as image2 in all cases.

Similarly if I am working with light backgrounds similar to that of the document then it fails to scan.

Now I want that actual functionality to be working in all the cases even holidng with hand or with light background. For that fix, I got suggestions that I need to work with react-native-camera.
Using that I have created a basic example where it opens the camera and some basic tests but nothing scans, so now I want either react-native-document-scanner to fix those bugs with camera or create another working example using react-native-camera
I need your help in both cases. I hope i was able to clarify my problems, still if something isn't clear please let me know. I'm running out of ideas and I do not find too much about this topic on the internet.
Thanks!
